# C++ class definition compile problems

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Ive looked all over and I cant find anything relating to my problem. Im trying to write a class definition for a polygon class that basicly has a vector that holds pointers to a point. When I try to compile i keep geting the folllowing errors...

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. 
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector'
error C2065: 'myPolygonPoints' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'points' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'myHasInstersection' : undeclared identifier
error C2660: 'Polygon::addSetOfPoints' : function does not take 1 arguments

Here is the code to the class

```
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>

class Point;

class Polygon
{
private:
    vector<Point*> myPolygonPoints;
    bool myHasIntersection;

public:
    void addSetOfPoints(vector<Point*> points)
    {
        myPolygonPoints = points;
    }

    bool getHasIntersection()
    {
        return myHasIntersection;
    }

    void setHasIntersection(bool intersection)
    {
        myHasInstersection = intersection;
    }

};
```

Comment: Stylistic note: it's kinder to present the `public` section first, then the `protected`, and finally the `private` one. A user of the class is only interested by the first (and perhaps the second in case of inheritance) and could not care less about the `private` one, so no need to have it in her eyes-path.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I'm always interested in seeing private details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `vector` from the `std` namespace without qualifying it.

You either have to do `using namespace std;`, or `using std::vector`, or declaring all your `vector` objects with the `std` namespace like `std::vector`.

```
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>

class Point; // Assuming Point.h has this declared,
             // you don't need this forward declaration, but in reality,
             // you don't need to include Point.h
             // since you're only declaring pointers to Points

class Polygon
{
private:
    std::vector<Point*> myPolygonPoints;
    bool myHasIntersection;

public:
    void addSetOfPoints(std::vector<Point*> points)
    {
        myPolygonPoints = points;
    }

    bool getHasIntersection()
    {
        return myHasIntersection;
    }

    void setHasIntersection(bool intersection)
    {
        myHasInstersection = intersection;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

vector is in the std:: namespace.  so vector is undefined in your example code

Two possible solutions:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

or: (in all cases through the code where you reference vector, both declaration and reference)

```
private:
  std::vector<Point*> myPolygonPoints;
public:
  void addSetOfPoints(std::vector<Point*> points)
```

etc.

---

A third solution is the following:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

This last one, from a coding style perspective, I find less preferred.  The reason is that it imports absolutely everything in the std namespace into the default namespace.  By contrast, I find it preferrable to explicitly import the pieces I'm using, becuase it allows me to keep track of why I need a header.  This doesn't make a sense in this case (of course I need `<Vector>`, I'm using std::vectors).  It's much more relevant in a case like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::adjacent_find;
```

Oh yeah, *that's* why I included that...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not explicitly declaring that you're using the std namespace you should reference which namespace vector belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `std::vector` problem, you have also mispelled the `myHasIntersection` variable in the `setHasIntersection` method.